# Firebase app with huge number of users on the same database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on an android app which is a coffee shop app that have creating of items and purchases with a stock management and reports the app may have 1000+ users on firebase and all the users are connected on the same database separated with the UserID which is unique
My question is that is it okay what i have done or it could make load on the firebase database since they are all connected on the same database if that is a problem should i create multiple databases for each user have his unique database not a unique id

Answer (score 0):

When you need to access each user info, firebase goes to that desired user and fetch the data, there is no need to shard your database into individual databases for each user.

You should shard your database into more databases if you exceed the limit of 100.000 simultaneous connections or 1000 write / sec operations, if you don't have reached this threshold, don't worry about sharding your database now.

If you have lets say, chat groups in your app, you can shard it to have a better performance for each group, but in this case, I don't see the reason to shard into individual users.

Documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding)

Comment: If the answer helped you, can you mark it as correct ? Thanks